# formatting of cron.allow and/or does cron need to be restarted

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I'm trying to setup a crontab specifically for the user that runs the web process.  I have root/sudo access so I wrote an entry for the www-data user using the -e option and here is the listing using the -l option:

```
/etc$ sudo crontab -u www-data -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
15,30,45 * * * * /var/www/cron/test.cli.php
```

The process is not running at the appointed interval however.  I'm pretty sure I have the syntax correct so this leads me to a few other possibilities

1) improperly formatted /etc/cron.allow?  I actually created this as sudo/root and all I've done is enter a line with "www-data" on it.  However, is this the correct format?  I'm having a hard time finding information on how /etc/cron.allow should be formatted, its *not* in the man as far as I can tell (http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)

2) Is /etc the correct location for cron.allow on Debian?  I googled and it mentions that it might go elsewhere under SUSE but all indications unless I'm mistaken is that under Debian /etc is the correct location.

3) Permissions for /etc/cron.allow?  I (temporarily) set them to 777, could this be *too* permissive?

4) Does cron need to be restarted after the creation/modification of cron.allow (or cron.deny)?

PS....since first posting this on stackoverflow (where I will now delete it) I have tried restarting cron to no avail: the task still does not run

Comment: 1) specifying (#!)/usr/bin/php would be superfluous I already begin my script that way and it runs from the command line and furthermore ....

2) I can run the task from root's crontab .... this seems to suggest that I have not properly setup the ability (via cron.allow?) for www-data to run it's own crontab

Comment: more or less identical situation (crontab for www-data user) but no solution see https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/crontab-and-process-permissions-442142/

Comment: I'm an idiot, it was a permissions problem within the script that was running.  Therefore I had actually properly setup the crontab for www-data.  Nevertheless I believe this question might be of value and will leave it stand.

Comment: It's always best to leave the questions on here, so someone in the future may benefit from what's been asked :)  Glad I could help point you in the right direction, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cornfed said, your .php script would have to start with #!/usr/bin/php for that to work.

1)  The cron.allow/deny files only affect a users ability to run the 'crontab' command, not the ability for a user to have a crontab.  See man crontab.

2)  Yes, also listed in man crontab.

3)  Yes, any user could add themselves to that list.  That's way too permissive.  But in most cases you *do not need this file* on Debian.  From man crontab:  "For standard Debian systems, all users may use this command."

4)  No, but I have noticed a delay in acceptance of new commands.  See /var/log/daemon (I think) for CRON's updating of it's internal files.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, please see the comments I've added to my question

Comment: ps....new command is accepted in a timely manner when adding to root's crontab

Comment: Thanks again, I have now actually removed the cron.allow I had previously created and crontab still runs the task for www-data, affirming what you write under #3 regarding probably not needing cron.allow on Debian

Answer (score 0):

You might try "15,30,45 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron/test.cli.php"